# Is it possible to create an HTML5 file that contains HTML, CSS, JS, NoUISlider, and Jquery code (not links to other files)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file

I have created a single working HTML5 file that contains HTML, CSS and JS. I would like to add (to the same file) NoUISlider and JQuery so that I can distribute a single file, rather than distributing a folder containing minified files of the above. Is this possible?.... Thank you.

Comment: Just copy the contents of `jquery.js` and `nouislider.js` into `<script>` tags, replacing the tags with `src="jquery.js"` and `src="nouislider.js"`.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar... I have in the head section of my HTML the following: <link href="nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="nouislider.js"></script>
    <script src="wNumb.js"></script>.     at the end of my HTML file I have <script> ...contents of (let's say) NoUISlider.js...</script>. Doesn't seem to work. I feel a bit silly, as all of this must be common knowledge, yet I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

Comment: Replace the `<link>` tags with `<style>` tags, and copy the contents of those CSS files into them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the tags that reference external files with equivalent tags that contain the contents of those files.

Replace

```
<link href="nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="nouislider.js"></script>
<script src="wNumb.js"></script>
```

with

```
<style>
copy contents of nuuislider.min.css here
</style>
<style>
copy contents of customstyle.css here
</style>
<script>
copy contents of nouislider.js here
</script>
<script>
copy contents of wNumb.js here
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!... for some reason the above didn't work if I pasted in the minified version of each js file, but the unminified version works perfectly. Thank you for your patience. Phew!